# Replace Multiple Instances of a Link in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some List items, which contain a div, which contains a link. I'd like to remove this Link from all the divs. This is my current function:

```
jQuery('.post_meta').each(function(){
    var el = jQuery('.post_meta a');
    el.html(el.html().replace(/, Slider/ig, ""));
});
```

This function dupolicates one div and add its contents to all the others. What would be the right way?

This is my markup:

```
<ul>
     <li>
         <div class="post_meta">
         <a href="#">Anything</a>, <a href="#">Slider</a>, <a href="#">Anything2</a> 
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could at least show us your markup

Comment: C'mon, don't be harsh with n00bs.

Comment: @DOK , i didn't get you ? what is nOObs?

Comment: Could you assign the links a CSS class, then change that class to make the links not display. Or change the CSS class to another class which is invisible?

Comment: @kobe: n00bs is slang for newbies. Here, Cindy only has one point, so she is a new user on SO and may not be familiar with how we do things around here. Her question is not a n00b question. Sometimes we drive away other smart people by slapping them down on their first attempt to get help from us.

Comment: Sorry @DOK, i didn't had any coffe at that time in the morning.

Comment: @DOK , you are right , we shouldn't scare people who just join ,

Comment: @Cindy , check my answer , you have to do a condition for your text..that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want something like this:

```
$('.post_meta a').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Slider";
}).remove();
```

This takes all links inside `.post_meta` elements and filters them by their content (whether the text is `Slider`. It then removes those elements.

**Reference:** [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), [`trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

**Update:** Regarding your comment. Removing the comma is a bit more tricky, but you can do it like this (after you removed the links):

```
$('.post_meta').each(function(){
    $.each($(this).contents(), function() {
        if(this.nodeType === 3) {
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/,\s*,/g, ',');
        }
    });
});
```

It is probably not very performant though...

**Update 2:** Apparently removing the comma did not work because after you removed the element node, you have two adjacent text nodes and not one.

This works though:

```
$('.post_meta').each(function(){
    var c = $(this).contents();
    $.each(c, function(i) {
        var prev = c[i-1];
        if(this.nodeType === 3 
           && prev 
           && prev.nodeType ===3
           && $.trim(this.nodeValue) === $.trim(prev.nodeValue)) {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpf3k/)

This basically removes duplicate adjacent text nodes.

**Why am I doing this so complicated?**

Because it looks there might be JavaScript event handlers attached to the links and if you get and set the HTML, these handlers will be lost.

If this is not the case and the HTML is really like this, you could do:

```
jQuery('.post_meta').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace('<a href="#">Slider</a>,','');
});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpf3k/1/)

But as said, this only works if (a) the HTML matches exactly with the string and (b) you don't bind any event handlers to the links (they will be lost).

Comment: Your first part works, the second doesn't. What about something like this: return $.trim($(this).html()) === ', <a href="#">Slider</a>'; I tried it, but it did not work.

Comment: @Cindy: That would depend on what `this` refers to in your example. I just tested it, the second part does not work because the two text nodes are not joined together... too bad.

Comment: How do I have to change the function I suggested, that it works?

Comment: @Cindy: Which function? In your question?

Comment: Yes, that one in my Question.

Comment: @Cindy: See the last part of my answer.

Comment: Many, Many Thanks for your efforts. I took the last one and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You use a each but dont fill in the function parameters, thes should be:

```
.each( function(index, Element) )
```

el are all links in all post_mpeta's

You could remove links with: `$(el).find('a').remove();` (in the each loop)

I don't get what your doing replaceing HTML

Comment: @garr_on I want to replace this html with nothing: , <a href="#">Slider</a> or remove it....

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do is this:

```
$(".post_meta a").remove();
```

If you want to clear all the other text you could do:

```
$(".post_meta").empty();
```

**UPDATE:**

Is it possible to change your markup? I would suggest adding a class to the anchor you want to remover, something like:

```
<ul>
     <li>
         <div class="post_meta">
         <a href="#">Anything</a>, <a href="#" class="slider">Slider</a>, <a href="#">Anything2</a> 
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you could do:

```
$(".post_meta a.slider").remove();
```

Comment: yes, but I want to remove only this one:  , <a href="#">Slider</a>  NOT THE OTHERS.

Comment: Yes, it would, but in this case I had to do it by jquery. And this for each link...this would slow down the performance

Answer (score 0):

Do this then:

```
var temp = $(el).find('a');

var txtVal = temp.text();

if(txtVal == "Slider")
{
    temp.remove();
}
```

Comment: I want to remove the coma before, too